# How about ARM/M1/M2 version

Tags: arm

Currently the only ARM/M1/M2 version of Ubuntu is the server one. How about providing a current desktop build along with a fairly useless server version. Surely the build tools can handle it. Debian does it, OpenSUSE does it.

Comment: Check out https://asahilinux.org/

Comment: This is a question answer site, ran by volunteers. It would be pointless to demand features in this site.

Comment: You can install the desktop GUI in Ubuntu Server with the command `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^`

Answer (score 0):

Official arm64 builds for Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 can be found at  https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/jammy/daily-live/current/

If a different release is desired, simply edit the URL.

Comment: You can also add that these ARM builds do not natively run in M1/M2 Macs, but may be virtualized